# Update Encrypted column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, encryption

I am using pgcrypto to encrypt and decrypt the table column. I want to know if I change the encryption key how to update existing records with the new key so that previous records can be decrypted with the new key. This is what I was trying to do.

```
Key 1: 
INSERT INTO info (name, ssn) values ('John',pgp_sym_encrypt('123-23-1211','key1');
SELECT name, pgp_sym_decrypt(ssn,'key1') from info;
```

Now, I want to use key2 so I want to update existing record with this new key. What should be the update query to do that?

Comment: You need to decrypt with the old key, then re-encrypt with the new key.

Comment: @Bergi and that's the part I am not able to figure out in terms of commands.

Comment: Just `SET ssn = pgp_sym_encrypt(pgp_sym_decrypt(ssn, 'key1'), 'key2')`, am I missing something?

Comment: @Bergi looks like i messed up with the command when I used it. Thanks this worked for me.